# Firestore Read operations calculation with stream limit change

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Implementing a chat app, it seems that **real time pagination** seems quiet complex with many edge cases given the constant addition and possible deletion of messages.

And so to avoid this, i'm wondering, if i use a stream that fetches the most recent 50 messages, then if a user scrolls up i increase the fetch limit to 200 and so on.

```
return firestore
          .collection("chatrooms")
          .doc(chatroomId)
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(documentLimit)
          .snapshots()
```

***Would that logic result in:
50 + 200 = 250 Reads. Or 50 + 150 = 200 Reads.?***

I've read the documentation, but i'm not to sure of the outcome for this case.

Comment: For chat app use realtime database and once a while migrate conversations to firestore. 1 bilion 1kkk messages in realtime database cost aroud 40-50$ and in firestore 1 000$.

Answer (score 3):

In the best case, you have local caching enabled and/or attach the new snapshot listener before removing the old one. In that case the 50 existing documents will be read from the cache, so you won't be charged for them as server-side document reads.

In the worst case, you've disabled local caching and attach the new listener after removing the old one. In that case, the 50 old documents are no longer present on the client, and thus also need to be read (and charged) from the server.

Comment: Local caching is enabled, How does one "attach the new snapshot listener before removing the old one", i'm disposing the initial stream when increasing the limit (Using riverpods autodispose feature) and directly creating the new stream with the new limit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @YassinSameh It do the magic for you. What ever request you make firebase on client side check first are you request it before and if you did it loads data you have and only checks are it is fresh. If not fresh it will download only documents where anything was change.

Comment: I had read that a cache read is still considered a read, is that only for the case of a get() request but not snapshots() ? Also do you know what frank meant with attaching the new listener before removing the old one? How can one do that or is my above mentioned flow of autodispose and creating a new stream correct? @FrankVanPuffelen